# How to fix System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ScanAPIHelper.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net

I didn't develop this software but I'm using it in my job. The software works for many machines but can't work on one of them. It is always giving the error:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ScanAPIHelper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.`

I have installed both windows x86 version and x64 version but to no avail. Please can someone help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem looks like you are missing the desired assembly or one of it's reference. (which is, what the error you are getting.)

I would suggest to download the [dependency_walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

And locate the dll (`ScanAPIHelper.dll`), If it's available, drag and drop it in `dependency walker` software and it will indicate which `dependent assembly is missing` or any other problem in your `dll/exe.`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay sure let me try now

Comment: @GideonAppoh Please verify the answer by accepting it so that it can help others.

Comment: Thanks man, I was missing the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

I had the project on a different drive other than C drive. After I moved it to C drive and ran the command it executed successfully.